Best way to convert Set<Id> into List<Account> in Apex?
What is the best way to convert Set<Id> (considering all Ids are of Account type) into List<Account> in Apex?

If you want to query them:
Account[] records = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN :idSet];

If you want to construct a list in memory for later use:
Account[] records = new Account[0];
for(Id accountId: idSet) {
  records.add(new Account(Id=accountId));
}


Thanks a lot, mate!

And sorry I cannot upvote - I was a brand new account, came back today to upvote but still cannot do it for the older posts.
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

@AloisPaprika No problem. I don't actually do this for the points anyways (it's just a side effect). Thanks for the kind words, though!
